# How to store an object in process.env variables

Tags: node.js, json, object, environment-variables, dotenv

I'm using firebase in my node js. application, and I want to store its serviceAccountKey.json file in a process.env variable.

Something like this in my dotenv (.env) file

```
  SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY={
  "type": "anything",
  "project_id": "anything",
  "private_key_id": "anything",
  "private_key": "anything",
  "client_email": "anything",
  "client_id": "anything",
  "auth_uri": "anything",
  "token_uri": "anything",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "anything",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "anything"
}
```

But when I do this, It says

> Service account must be an object.

Please help me storing this object in process.env variable.

Answer (score 5):

You could try to store the object as a string and parse it as JSON in your code.

*.env* :

```
MY_VAR='{"a":"valueA","b":"valueB"}'
```

Then in the code 
*app.js* :

```
let object = JSON.parse(process.env.MY_VAR);
```

**EDIT** ( thanks @Luca Galasso ) Reformed a correct JSON string.

Comment: now it says "Failed to parse private key"

Comment: Try to check the content of your env variable before parsing it into JSON. I'll edit my answer, there might be issues with character escaping !

Comment: the given string is not in JSON string valid format. It is missing the `"` before the object keys. The correct string should be `'{"a":"valueA","b":"valueB"}'`

Comment: @tdonnenfeld Failed to parse private key: Error: Invalid PEM formatted message.

Comment: @Saad8113 I think this is a different question. ( Trying to store a multiline string in an environment variable maybe ? )

Comment: Does it work if the JSON has a `'` character? eg: `value'A`

Answer (score 0):

When storing a variable in the `process.env`, it will be automatically converted as a string.

Given that, if you'd like to set a variable in the `process.env`, either you pass a proper string object-like while running your script:

```sh
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY='{"type":"anything"}' node script.js
```

or you cast the object to a string in your script.js file like:

```js
process.env.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY = JSON.parse(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY)
```

In both cases, while reading your variable from the process.env, you should convert it to an object:

```js
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY = JSON.parse(process.env.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY)
```

---

Since the error you wrote says "... must be an object.", most probably the missing piece is the last step (parsing from string to object).

Comment: "Failed to parse private key: Error: Invalid PEM formatted message".

Comment: what I did was first I took the value from `JSON.stringify({serviceAccountKey})` and then I assigned this string value to a variable in my .env file like this `SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY='{whatever I got from stringify}'`

Comment: and while reading this value I did this `serviceAccountKey=JSON.parse(process.env.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY)` and I'm getting this error **Failed to parse private key: Error: Invalid PEM formatted message.**

Answer (score 0):

In .env file:

```
MY_VAR='{"a":"valueA","b":"valueB"}'
```

In app.js file:

```
const serviceAccount = JSON.parse(process.env.MY_VAR);
```

instead of

```
const serviceAccount = require(JSON.parse(process.env.MY_VAR));
```

remove require and ().

Sample:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue while developing a SvelteKit app with Firebase Auth. SvelteKit has some features that protect from importing private environment variables into public code, which is what the `import { FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY } from "$env/static/private";` is all about (see below). If you are not using SvelteKit, then you can use `process.env.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY` like others have used in this thread.

This is what I did:

**in my `.env` file:**

```
FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY = `{
  "type": "anything",
  "project_id": "anything",
  "private_key_id": "anything",
  "private_key": "anything",
  "client_email": "anything",
  "client_id": "anything",
  "auth_uri": "anything",
  "token_uri": "anything",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "anything",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "anything"
}`
```

Since environment variables need to be strings, I wrapped the object in back ticks. However, it doesn't appear that you *have to* use back ticks because this also worked for me when I used single quotes too. And I was able to preserve the multi-line object structure with both back ticks and single quotes.

**In my `/lib/firebase/server/index.ts` file (which is just a server-side file):**

```
import { cert, getApps, initializeApp } from "firebase-admin/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase-admin/auth";
import { FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY } from "$env/static/private";

// Initialize Firebase Admin for a SvelteKit app.
function makeApp() {
  const apps = getApps();
  if (apps.length > 0) {
    return apps[0]!;
  }

  return initializeApp({
    credential: cert(JSON.parse(FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY)),
  });
}

export const firebase = makeApp();
export const auth = getAuth(firebase);
```

**Some Notes About Production Deployments:**

If you are wondering whether you should store your private key in a public repository, like GitHub, or not, this should be helpful. When you generate a new private key, Google gives you this warning:

**Your private key gives access to your project's Firebase services. Keep it confidential and never store it in a public repository.**

I have seen some tutorials that have you separate each property of the `FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY` into separate environment variables and then import and reference each of those environment variables individually. That gets a little messy, especially when you want to store your environment variables in your web host's environment variables storage.

The approach I used, with back ticks and `JSON.parse()`, also allowed me to easily store these variables in my web host's environment variables storage. Just remember that when you store the JSON object for `FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY` in your web host's environment variables storage, do NOT include the back ticks (or single quotes) around the object. I accidentally did that and got strange errors that took me a while to debug.